# How to fill data from similar columns into a particular column(pandas)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a script that converts files.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample1.csv")
final_df = df.reindex(['id','name','email'],axis=1)
final_df.to_csv("output.csv", index = False)
```

sample1.csv

```
|name|email|id|
|--|  -- |  -- |
```

output.csv

```
|id|name|email|
|--|  -- |  -- |
```

Now, if the other sample files are in the format like below, how to arrange them in the format same as output.csv

sample2.csv

```
|id|first name |email address|
 |--|  -- |  -- | 
 |1 | Sta |sta@example.com|
 |2 |Danny|dany@example.com|
 |3 |Elle |elle@example.com|
```

sample3.csv

```
|id|initial name |email id|
 |--|  -- |  -- | 
 |1 | Ricky|ricky@example.com|
 |2 |Sham|sham@example.com|
 |3 |Mark|@example.com|
```

sample4.csv

```
 | id |alias|contact|
 |-- |  -- |  -- | 
 | 1 | Ricky|ricky@example.com|
 |2 |Sham|sham@example.com|
 |3 |Mark|@example.com|
```

I want to convert these files and place them in the columns of output file. For example, first name, initial name, alias refers to name(all means same), and email address, email id, and contact should refer to email. The order of columns can be random in the sample files.

The basic illustration for this case is :

```
switch(headerfields[i])
{ 
   case "firstname":
   case "initial name":
   case "alias":
      name = i;

}
```

Any ideas to do this in Pandas?

Comment: is the order the same in each dataframe?

Comment: No, It can be different. Actually, I want to create a new output file with new headers and those fields should take reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
import pandas as pd
sample1 = pd.read_csv('sample1.csv')

def mapping(df):
    for column_name, column in df.transpose().iterrows():
        df.rename(columns ={'first name' : 'FNAME', 'email address': 'EMAIL'}, inplace = True)
        df.rename(columns ={'alias' : 'FNAME', 'contact': 'EMAIL'}, inplace = True)
        df.rename(columns ={'initial name' : 'FNAME', 'emailid': 'EMAIL'}, inplace = True)

mapping(sample1)
```

Comment: I don't know why you use `for` loop in the function. and the mapping func is same as `df.rename(columns = {'first name' : 'FNAME', 'email address': 'EMAIL','alias' : 'FNAME', 'contact': 'EMAIL', 'initial name' : 'FNAME', 'emailid': 'EMAIL'}, inplace = True)`

Answer (score 1):

Select the target columns, then append to the target DataFrame.

```py
dfn = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'name', 'email'])
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    # select columns
    cond_list = [
                df.columns =='id', 
                df.columns.str.contains('name|alias', na=False),
                df.columns.str.contains('email|contact', na=False)
    ]
    cols = [df.columns[cond][0] for cond in cond_list]
    print(cols)
    dfn = dfn.append(pd.DataFrame(df[cols].values, columns=dfn.columns))
```

output:

```
['id', 'first name', 'email address']
['id', 'initial name', 'email id']
['id', 'alias', 'contact']
```

dfn:

```
  id   name              email
0  1    Sta    sta@example.com
1  2  Danny   dany@example.com
2  3   Elle   elle@example.com
0  1  Ricky  ricky@example.com
1  2   Sham   sham@example.com
2  3   Mark       @example.com
0  1  Ricky  ricky@example.com
1  2   Sham   sham@example.com
2  3   Mark       @example.com
```

---

Testing data:

```
df_str = '''
id  "first name"    "email address"
1   Sta sta@example.com
2   Danny   dany@example.com
3   Elle    elle@example.com
'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str.strip()), sep='\s+', index_col=False)

df_str = '''
id  "initial name"  "email id"
1   Ricky   ricky@example.com
2   Sham    sham@example.com
3   Mark    @example.com

'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str.strip()), sep='\s+', index_col=False)

df_str = '''
id  alias   contact
1   Ricky   ricky@example.com
2   Sham    sham@example.com
3   Mark    @example.com
'''
df3 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str.strip()), sep='\s+', index_col=False)


df1['1'] = 1
df2['2'] = 2
df3['3'] = 3

df1.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
df3.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution, but you could test the first 5 rows of each dataframe for certain strings/numbers and assume that's your target column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def rename_and_merge_dfs(dfs : list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    new_dfs = []
    for frame in dfs:
    
        id_col = frame.head(5).select_dtypes(np.number).columns[0]
        email = frame.columns[frame.head(5).replace('[^@]','',regex=True).eq('@').all()][0]
        name = list(set(frame.columns) - set([id_col, email]))[0]

        frame = frame.rename(columns={id_col : 'id', email : 'email', name : 'name'})
        new_dfs.append(frame)
        
    return pd.concat(new_dfs)
```

---

```
final = rename_and_merge_dfs([df3,df2,df1])

print(final)

   id    name              email
1   1   Ricky  ricky@example.com
2   2    Sham   sham@example.com
3   3    Mark       @example.com
0   1   Ricky  ricky@example.com
1   2    Sham   sham@example.com
2   3    Mark       @example.com
0   1     Sta    sta@example.com
1   2   Danny   dany@example.com
2   3    Elle   elle@example.com
```

Comment: I don't want to concat those columns

Comment: Right, just saw your edit @AtomStore the code is pretty straight forward, can you edit it to get your output?